# Is there a way to force unmount a component?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

In my mobile app, I have a screen that have tab navigation. In the first tab, I want to add a back handler to exit the app. But in other tabs, I don't want that to happen. I implemented this like given below.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.handleBackButtonClick = this.handleBackButtonClick.bind(this);
  this.state = {};
}

componentWillMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
}

handleBackButtonClick() {
  BackHandler.exitApp();
  return true;
}
```

This functionality works fine in first tab. But my problem is, in other tabs as well, when I click back button, app exits. I want a different functionality in those tabs. According to my studies, tab navigation doesn't call componentWillUnmount. So, it doesn't remove the event listner on tab navigation. 
But I couldn't find another solution.

If there is any solution to implement exit app functionality in first tab only, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/force-unmount-component

Answer (score 1):

You can set a state and check that in handleBackButton.
For example if you're using react-navigation you can add something like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        if (route.name === 'First tab') {
             this.setState({canExit: true});
        }
        else {
            this.setState({canExit: false});
        }
    })}
/>
```

then you can change the handler like this:

```
handleBackButtonClick() {
    if(this.state.canExit){
       BackHandler.exitApp();
    }
    return true;
}
```